# Why goodness is taught and hailed?

Tags: dharma, life

*Why goodness is taught and hailed?*. It is taught in our holy texts that certain behavioural attributes and attitudes are way to attain bramah. Why only such traits can bring you enlightenment and can set you free? Why not bad traits hailed and have same value as good ones?

Comment: Because Dharma prevails and Satyameva Jayate.  Related or a possible duplicate  of  [Are Hindu scriptures (itihasas) written from the winners' perspective?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18547/5212)

Comment: @user12737 if you want a reason-based perspective, the Ethics of Aristotle would probably provide a good foundation. In Hindu works, I am not sure if there is a reason to follow Dharma.

Comment: @user1952500 Do you means Nichomachean Ethics?

Comment: @user12737 yes. I am a novice in Hindu dharma but I haven’t found a reasonable definition of ‘good’, and if dharma is aligned with ‘good’. It is probably assumed in all works or is of an unquestionable nature. Maybe some others in the site know better.

Comment: @user1952500 Have read that work of aristotle?

Comment: BTW, goodness may not be a path to Brahman. I did not read the second part of the question carefully enough. There are various aspects to goodness (ahimsa etc) which are useful in life but good actions alone are not enough.

Comment: @user1952500 My question is: Why goodness only? Why bad deeds cannot?

Comment: It’s a valid question and I don’t have an answer. My thoughts are that good is defined to be that which leads to higher states while bad is defined to be that which doesn’t lead to these states.(in Hinduism that is)

Comment: @user1952500 As par my knowledge in every religion its the same(reply to your last comment).

Comment: Yeah that’s why it’s a tough question.

Comment: It’s sort of tough to formulate ethics and that’s one reason why the book also takes some time to define it. We can see that in many cases Hinduism approaches the definition. Not many religions come close to the ‘general understanding’ of ethics that we have.

Comment: Decide things when you are young if you can. Don't get too complicated or you will never decide on anything. This matter concerns you or you would not ask this question. The good ones ask these questions, the bad ones don't care.  May I suggest:  do your duty. Do it.  Find it and do it to the best of your ability. We are none perfect.   Do the deed, don't wring you hands over it or you will waste much time in life.